# Drupal 7 views how to modify where clause?

Tags: drupal, view, glossary

I have a situation whereby i have to add a 0-9 link in the contextual filter of the glossary view

How do i change the where clause part?
i need to change

```
SUBSTRING(node.title, 1, :node_title) = :node_title1
```

to

```
SUBSTRING(node.title, 1, 1) =REGEXP ('[0-9]')
```

if certain value == '0-9'
i tried to implement hook_views_query_alter but it is not working

```
function  custom_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query){

  $current_view=&$view;

  switch($current_view->name){

    case  'glossary':

  if($query->where[0]['conditions'][0]['value'][':node_title1']=='0-9'){
    $query->where[0]['conditions'][0]['field']= "SUBSTRING(node.title, 1, 1) =REGEXP ('[0-9]')";
    echo "YES";

    dpm($query->where);
        }  } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working here's the code

```
function  custom_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query){

$current_view=&$view;
switch($current_view->name){

case  'glossary':
  if($query->where){

  if($query->where[0]['conditions'][0]['value'][':node_title1']=="0-9"){
       $query->where[0]['conditions'][0]['field'] = "SUBSTRING(node.title, 1, 1) REGEXP ('[0-9]')";
    dpm($query->where);
 }

}
}
}
```